# Не срабатывает клик на добавленной кнопке

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

```
<b id="info">тут есть текст</b>

$('.show').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '123',
        success: function(data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#info').html(json.text+'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success check">кнопка</button>');
        }
    }); 
})
$('.check').on('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: '123',
   success: function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        if(json.check == 'ok'){
            location.reload();
         }
    }
  }); 
})
```

Не могу разобраться почему при добавлении кнопки на страницу, в дальнейшем она не хочет работать

Comment: `$('#info').on('click', '.check', function() { ...` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Igor, то что надо

Comment: [Прямая и делегированная обработка](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29)

Answer (score 0):

Для динамических элементов используется делегированная обработка событий, выглядит примерно так:

```
$('parent').on('event', 'children', function(e){
    //Какое-то действие
});
```

Где parent - это статичный родительский элемент,
event - событие,
children - дочерний динамический элемент, на котором обработчик и должен сработать.